# keyboard for telegram bot in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram

I'm writing a bot in JavaScript for telegram messenger using npm package manager
I encountered such a problem that I don’t know how to use the reply_markup buttons correctly
Now my bot looks like this
[image]

```
const mainMenuButton = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{text: 'Bot information', callback_data: 'info'}], 
            [{text: 'Exchange Rates', callback_data: 'currencies'}]
        ]
    }) 
}

let startBot = () => {
    
    bot.setMyCommands([
        { command: '/start', description: 'Initial greeting' }
    ]);

    bot.on('text', msg => {
        let text = msg.text;
        let chatId = msg.chat.id;

        if (text === '/start') {
            return bot.sendMessage(chatId, `Hello, ${msg.from.first_name}, how can I help you?`, mainMenuButton);
        }
    });

    bot.on('callback_query', async (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        let data = msg.data;
        let chatId = msg.message.chat.id;

        if (data === 'info') {
            return bot.sendMessage(chatId, "This is my first project", mainMenuButton);
        }
    })
}
```

I want to make buttons like this
[image]

And I made them but I don’t know how to access them

```
const testButton = {
    reply_markup:{
        keyboard: [
            ['Bot information'], 
            ['Exchange Rates']
        ],
        resize_keyboard: true
    }
}
```

Comment: YOur question is unclear.

Comment: What are the options for implementing a keyboard for a telegram bot in javascript? I showed one implementation of the keyboard in my question
~~~
const mainMenuButton = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{text: 'Bot information', callback_data: 'info'}], 
            [{text: 'Exchange Rates', callback_data: 'currencies'}]
        ]
    }) 
}
~~~